# Log4j logging all events which are not caught by the defined loggers

Tags: logging, log4j

I have a little problem.

I am using log4j 1.2.17, and I want to log all logs that come from all packages for which I don't have a logger specified.
For example:
In my application I have multiple frameworks that I use: primefaces, solr, atmosphere, etc.
I had configured a log4j.xml for logging the app logs. It works great, I also put "org.primefaces" package into a logger for restricting the INFO logs.
But now, in the console, for which doesn't even exists an appender, because I don't want to have app output without being logged, appear logs from atmosphere. Not a big problem because I can put another logger for this, but I don't want to do this. Why? Because in the future could appear another frameworks for which I will have to add another logger. My log4j config file will be monstrous.

How can I create a logger for logging the entire output which is not caught by the already defined loggers?

If the problem is not well explained please let me know and I will add the required information.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a root for logging the entire output which is not caught by the already defined loggers.

```
<root>
    <appender-ref ref="rootAppender " />
</root>
```

And if you want not to propagate a logging event to the root then add the additivity flag to false in those loggers.

```
<logger name="org.primefaces" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="orgPrimefacesAppender" />
</logger>
```